# How to divide a range of cells by 1000 and return a decimal in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am very novice to VBA and I have solved some tough problems except this one which seems so easy.

On my Worksheet("Behavioral Data") I have numbers in the cell range ("B2:B217") such as "125, 1590, 0, 3343, etc."

**I want to divide these numbers by 1000, then replace the current cells with the newly divided decimals.**

Comment: `For Each q In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Behavioral Data").Range("B2:B217"): q = q / 1000: Next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a `Range` and iterate over it in order to get each cell value and replace it with a new value:

```
Private Sub DivideAndReplace()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Behavioral Data").Range("B2:B217")

For Each c In rng
    c.Value = c.Value / 1000
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Without a loop:

```
Sub divideandconquer()
    With Sheets("Behavioral Data").Range("B2:B217")
        .Value = Evaluate("=" & .Address & " / 1000")
    End With
End Sub
```